# re-render as soon as the state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rerender

I have app.js file like so

```
export const App = () => {

const [selectedMeals, setSelectedMeals] = useState<string[]>(["allItems"]);

  const onCheckHandler = (e: any) => {
    const checkedValue = e.target.value;
    if (e.target.checked && checkedValue !== "allItems") {
      setSelectedMeals(
        [...new Set([...selectedMeals, checkedValue])].filter(
          (item) => item !== "allItems"
        )
      );
    } else if (e.target.checked && checkedValue === "allItems") {
      setSelectedMeals(["allItems"]);
    } else {
      setSelectedMeals(selectedMeals.filter((item) => item !== checkedValue));
    }
  };

return (
      <MenuFilter
                    onClick={hideMenuModalHandler}
                    onCheck={onCheckHandler}
                    checkedItems={selectedMeals}
                  />
     
  );


}
```

The menu filter in turn uses a `checkbox` component to render several check boxes & the checked status of these checkboxes depends on the `selectedMeals` prop that i pass to the menufilter component

```
export const MenuFilter = ({
  onClick,
  onCheck,
  checkedItems,
}: MenuFilterProps) => {
  const excelDataContextObject = useContext(excelDataContext);
  const excelData = excelDataContextObject.excelData;

  const colorModeState = useContext(colorModeContext);
  const toggled = colorModeState.toggled;

  let meals = [...new Set(excelData.map((item: menuItem) => item.Meal))];


  return (
    <Modal filterItems={meals} toggled={toggled} onClick={onClick}>
      <div
        className={`${styles["modal-header"]}  grid ${
          toggled ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light"
        }`}
      >
        Filter Menu
      </div>

      <div
        className={`${styles["menu-filter"]}  grid ${
          toggled ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light"
        }`}
      >
        <CheckBox
          key={"allItems"}
          standAlone={false}
          text={"All Items"}
          onCheck={onCheck}
          isChecked={checkedItems.includes("allItems")}
          value={"allItems"}
        />
        {meals.map((meal: string) => (
          <CheckBox
            key={meal}
            standAlone={false}
            text={meal}
            onCheck={onCheck}
            isChecked={checkedItems.includes(meal)}
            value={meal}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className={`${styles["modal-footer"]}`}>
        <button
          className={`${styles.ok} ${toggled ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light"}`}
        >
          OK
        </button>
        <button
          className={`${styles.cancel} ${
            toggled ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light"
          }`}
          onClick={onClick}
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

I read that when the state is passed as a prop, the re-rendering happens as soon as the state changes but this is not happening.

The `selectedMeals` state is initialized with `allItems` and then managed such that when any other items is click, that items is set & `allItems` and these `individual` items can be several at once. The state management works fine but the checkbox is not getting updated based on the state!

See the video here (https://youtu.be/Zmfc0MQGaIU) where the state change (`allItems` gets removed & when `allItems` is checked other items get removed) works perfectly but the check boxes are not re-rendering appropriately

What am I doing wrong & more importantly how do I get the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

It's because setSomething() only re renders the component if and only if the previous and current state is different. Since arrays in javascript are reference types, if you edit an item of an array in js, it still doesn't change the reference to the original array. In js's eyes, these two arrays are the same, even though the original content inside those arrays are different. That's why setSomething() fails do detect the changes made to the old array. to correct this you need to use spread operator ie. spreading the old values and adding new values.

In your case you can try

```
 setSelectedMeals([...selectedMeals, "allItems"]);
```

Comment: This is not working. `setSelectedMeals([...selectedMeals, "allItems"]);` would just add `"allItems"` to the array

Comment: I just gave you a example not exact code, what I'm trying to tell you here is you need to use spread operator when you set Values using react usehook setSomething()

Comment: I understand. I already use spread operator in my use-effect. When i use `setSelectedMeals(["allItems"])`. I am actually passing a totally new array, so this need not be changed.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox of this code, I will help you.